# vaadin DateTime Milliseconds

Tags: datetime, datepicker, vaadin

How can I force vaadin 8 DateTimeField set resolution in milliseconds?

Actually I'm doing like that..

```
dateTimeField.setResolution(DateTimeResolution.SECOND);
```

The [`DateTimeResolution`](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.4/com/vaadin/shared/ui/datefield/DateTimeResolution.html) class only accepts an enum type with the highest resolution of `SECOND`.

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Comment: You will have to make your own picker. Simplest way would be to compose it of the standard picker + a input field for the millisecond amount

Comment: If your users are supposed to also enter the ms into the input field, i'd assume, that they are just some data drones copying from another source?  Maybe at that point its easier to just have a textfield with a converter.